# iOS 8: Storyboard - Delegate for UIPopoverController

Tags: swift, ios8, uistoryboardsegue

Starting with a single view controller app template. I added a button on the main view controller and second view controller, then I attached the button to the second view controller with a storyboard segue presented as a popover.

Sadly, the segue sent into the `prepareForSegue:sender:` method is not a `UIStoryboardPopoverSegue`. Is it possible to attach delegates to a storyboard segue's popover?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPopoverControllerDelegate {

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if let popoverSegue = segue as? UIStoryboardPopoverSegue {
            popoverSegue.popoverController.delegate = self
        }

    }

    func popoverControllerDidDismissPopover(popoverController: UIPopoverController) {
        println("dismissed")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had the same issue recently. In iOS 8, you can access the UIPopoverPresentationController and set the [UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014328) (rather than the UIPopoverController and -Delegate) through the [`popoverPresentationController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/popoverPresentationController) of the destinationViewController, using this code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if let controller = segue.destinationViewController as? UIViewController {
        controller.popoverPresentationController.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a great answer!

Comment: Have the same issue, doesn't work for me though :/ what could be the reason for this? By the way I have to use an exclamation point after the popoverPresentationController, otherwise it wouldn't set the delegate. As a result I get and error EXC_BREAKPOINT